# ES6 and type definitions: dynamically assign a type to a super class' property and for intellisense

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, types, type-definition

With es6, say I have a base class:

```
export class BaseClass {
  constructor(meta) {
    this.meta = Object.assign({}, { alwaysPresent: 'some value' }, meta);
  }
}
```

and a sub class class:

```
import { BaseClass } from './base-class';
import childMeta from './child-meta';

export class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
  constructor() {
    super(childMeta);
  }

  fn() {
    this.meta.property1;
  }
}
```

with `childMeta` being:

```
export default {
  property1: 'property1Value',
  property2: 'property2Value'
};
```

How do i create a `base-class.d.ts` so that when I do `this.meta` i would be able to see the properties from `childMeta`?

something like this:

[image]

current `base-class.d.ts`

```
export class BaseClass {
  protected meta: { property1: string; property2: string }; // for illustration purposes
}
```

**Notes:**

- `childMeta` can literally be any js object with any property
- multiple classes will be extending the base class
- im mostly after the intellisense, really. im using vscode for this.

So far I've tried reading on a few dynamic types tutorials but i can't seem to make it work.

Is what i need even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a type that is based on `childMeta` using

```
type ChildMeta = typeof childMeta;
```

Given that, it depends on what exactly you want to do with that type.

- If you want to define the type of `meta` in `BaseClass`, add the field with a type:

  ```
  meta: ChildeMeta;
  ```
- If only the subclass should get the type annotation, you could use a type assertion:

  ```
  super(childMeta as ChildMeta);
  ```